# Convert android app to web app

Tags: android, web-applications, apk

i made this app for android using Android Studio that is kind of like a game, and i wanted to make the same thing but on a website, is there any simple way to do this? Or do i have to write the whole code all over again (i.e. using HTML, CSS, Javascript)?

Answer (score 0):

> is there any simple way to do this?

No

> Or do i have to write the whole code all over again (i.e. using HTML, CSS, Javascript)?

exactly